# Нужна помощь в разработке приложения на WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть проблема, которую я не могу решить долгий период времени, она заключается в том, что я разрабатываю динамический конструктор тестов. Конструктор должен иметь возможность давать пользователю создавать неограниченное количество вопросов с одним вариантов ответа: множеством вариантов и текстовым ответом, без ограничения количества вариантов ответа в одном вопросе. То есть пользователь будет динамически создавать и изменять объекты через интерфейс, соответственно мне необходимо чтобы работала привязка TwoWay. Я нашел только одно решение спустя множество, экспериментов которое работает, но мне не нравиться как оно реализовано. Были созданы 3 класса представляющие собой варианты ответов CheckBoxItem, RadioButtomItem и TextItem, также они были унаследованы от интерфейса IItem позже объясню почему
Пример одного из классов:

```
[Serializable]
public class CheckBoxItem : IItem
{
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => text = value;
    }

    private bool correctAnswer = false;
    public bool CorrectAnswer
    {
        get => correctAnswer;
        set => correctAnswer = value;
    }

    public bool Compare(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is CheckBoxItem cb)
        {
            if (correctAnswer == cb.correctAnswer)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Для составления самого вопроса был создан класс Question

```
[Serializable]
public class Question
 {
     private string questionName;
     public string QuestionName
     {
         get => questionName;
         set =>  questionName = value;
     }

     public ObservableCollection<IItem> Items { get; set; }
     = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();
 }
```

В коллекцию будут помещаться CheckBoxItem, RadioButtomItem и TextItem в зависимости от типа вопроса.

В ViewModels самого конструктора используеться следующий код:

```
internal class Create_LoadWindowViewModel : ViewModel, ICloseWindows
    {
        IFileService fileService;

        DialogService dialogService;

        bool editTest;

        Test test;

        public bool CanClose()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public Action Close{ get; set; } = () => { MessageBox.Show("Save test?"); };

        public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

        private Question selectedQuestion = new Question();
        public Question SelectedQuestion
        {
            get => selectedQuestion;
            set
            {
                Set(ref selectedQuestion, value);
            }
        }

        private IItem selectedItem;
        public IItem SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set
            {
                Set(ref selectedItem, value);
            }
        }

        public string testName;
        public string TestName
        {
            get => testName;
            set
            {                
                    Set(ref testName, value);
            }
        }

        COMMANND
methods
       
        public Create_LoadWindowViewModel(DialogService dialogService, IFileService fileService, Test test, bool editTest)
        {
            this.dialogService = dialogService;
            this.fileService = fileService;
            Questions = test.Questions;
            TestName = test.Name;
            this.test = test;
            this.editTest = editTest;
        }
    }
```

Минус данного подхода заключается в том, что мне доступен только BinaryFormatter так, как только он может сериализовать интерфейс используемы в классе Question как тип коллекции, json и XML сериализации выдают ошибку.
Я пробивал заменить класс Question на `Question<T>` что приводит к большему количеству проблем также были попытки сократить класс  Question использую кортежи но тогда нельзя динамически изменять объекты через пользовательский интерфейс.
Подробнее можно ознакомиться на https://github.com/Kowari1/TestBuilder
Хочется узнать каким образом вы бы реализовали данную задачу

Comment: У вас так много всего, а вопрос по сути сводится к "Ошибка сериализации в JSON/XML"... Так может стоит акцентировать внимание на ошибке, приложить ее, показать как пытались серализовать, составить простые классы, которые воспроизводят проблему? И это какой язык? C#, верно? Ну так, где метка нужного языка? Вопрос ведь с WPF вообще не связан, от него можно вовсе абстрагироваться, раз проблема с сериализацией.

Comment: Суть в подходе который не позволяет использовать  json и XML сериализации и мне понятно почему выходит ошибка, суть в том что я не могу придумать лучший вариант построение динамически создаваемого конструктора тестов чем тот который у меня уже есть. Вопрос непосредственно относиться к WPF, так как мне пришлось все так усложнить из-за двусторонней привязки к интерфейсу без которой не обойтись, я просто хочу услышать мнение других пользователей по тому как они изменили бы мой код или предложили совсем другой подход чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы

Comment: Не вижу в этом коде проблем с JSON/XML. Также не вижу каких либо усложнений кода, вполне себе лаконичный и понятный. Единственное, нарушаете Mvvm, ибо диалоги это view слой, а вы ими руководите в VM, который ничего этого делать не должен.

Comment: JSON/XML не позволяют сериализовать интерфейс, который используется здесь:                                                                                                                     ```                                                                                                                    
     public ObservableCollection<IItem> Items { get; set; }
     = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();                                                                                                                         
 ```

Comment: Все они могут, их надо просто грамотно настроить, чтоб они запоминали конкретный тип, и т.д. Вам вот не кажется странным, что самый популярный формат вдруг не умеет работать с самым популярным функционалом языка?

Comment: Можете тогда пожалуйста подсказать где можно узнать как это сделать

Comment: Зависит от того, что используете, какой сериализатор. К примеру стандартный System.Text.Json с этим всем справляется [при помощи атрибутов](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism), где вы задаете какой тип может реализовывать этот интерфейс и задаете также его `$type`, получаете что-то типа [этого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xpuw6Y). Если используете Json.net, то там просто в опциях достаточно включить сохранение типа. Что касается XML, то это не ко мне, я этот формат считаю старым, но, там также можно указывать тип.